# Accesing a JPanel variable from another class in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have two classes, the JFrame class and the class for an individual panel (I will be using CardLayout). My panel class extends my JFrame class, but I want to be able to access my panel in the JFrame class so that I can add it to the JFrame from there. (I will do this from a different CardLayout class later, but for now I am doing it from the JFrame class).

Here is the panel class:

```
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class ECLoginPanel extends ECFrame {
    public JPanel LoginPanel;
    public JButton login;
    public JButton signup;
    
    public ECLoginPanel() {
        Color darkblue = new Color(24, 40, 85);
        Color lightblue = new Color(78, 159, 206);
        Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
        
        login = new JButton("Login");
        signup = new JButton("Signup");
        
        LoginPanel.setBackground(darkblue);
        LoginPanel.add(login);
        LoginPanel.add(signup);
        
        login.setFont(new Font("HelveticaNeue", Font.BOLD, 20)); 
        login.setBackground(lightblue);
        login.setFocusPainted(false);
        login.setBorder(emptyBorder);
        
        signup.setFont(new Font("HelveticaNeue", Font.BOLD, 20));
        signup.setBackground(lightblue);    
        signup.setFocusPainted(false);
        signup.setBorder(emptyBorder);
    }
}
```

And here is the frame class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ECFrame {
    JFrame frame;
    
    public ECFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame("EasyChat v0.01");
        frame.setSize(800,450);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `frame.add(new ECLoginPanel());`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer when I do that in the JFrame class there is an error on .add since ECLoginPanel is a class, not a component. When I just do frame.add(LoginPanel); I get an error on LoginPanel since it cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: Change `extends ECFrame` to `extends JPanel`, also make sure the imports are correct

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you very much, however it still is not working and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Your questions suggest that you might benefit from going through some basic Swing tutorials to learn the nuts and bolts of how GUI's are constructed and the logic that underpins how it's done. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to add `LoginPanel` to `frame`.

Your `ECLoginPanel` already has a `frame` (because it inherits it from `ECFrame`).

So you just need to call `frame.add(LoginPanel);` (assuming both your classes are on the same package) as the last line of `ECLoginPanel`'s constructor.

But you are setting your `frame` to visible in the constructor of `ECFrame` (which is called before `ECLoginPanel`'s constructor), so you should also revalidate and repaint the frame after adding the `LoginPanel`.

So replace the code of `ECLoginPanel` to:

```
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class ECLoginPanel extends ECFrame {
    public JPanel LoginPanel;
    public JButton login;
    public JButton signup;
    
    public ECLoginPanel() {
        Color darkblue = new Color(24, 40, 85);
        Color lightblue = new Color(78, 159, 206);
        Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
        
        login = new JButton("Login");
        signup = new JButton("Signup");
        
        LoginPanel.setBackground(darkblue);
        LoginPanel.add(login);
        LoginPanel.add(signup);
        
        login.setFont(new Font("HelveticaNeue", Font.BOLD, 20)); 
        login.setBackground(lightblue);
        login.setFocusPainted(false);
        login.setBorder(emptyBorder);
        
        signup.setFont(new Font("HelveticaNeue", Font.BOLD, 20));
        signup.setBackground(lightblue);    
        signup.setFocusPainted(false);
        signup.setBorder(emptyBorder);

        //Added the following 3 lines...
        frame.add(LoginPanel);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }
}
```

... and let us know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to use a CardLayout, and therefore need to add the different panels in one class, but don't want to construct the GUI in the CardLayout class?

Comment: Then move your `JFrame` creation code outside the `CardLayout` panel's constructor. You are not required to put the `frame`'s initialization code into the constructor (you can put it after the objects/panels are constructed).

Comment: Unrelated to the original question but... my buttons and all my other GUI is not showing up, I have just a blank panel.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect your current code (so that me and/or others will be able to answer it), or post another question.